# Painting a different image to a JButton when the JButton is clicked

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jbutton

I am busy making a game in Java. I am however struggling with getting the GUI to work properly.

What I am struggling with:

When the button is pressed I want it to display a coloured circle, when the button is pressed again I want it to paint a circle AROUND the old circle, this can happen till a max of four circle on each button. (So there is a small circle, medium circle etc) 
Does anybody have a good idea how to do this? Painting a circle for the first time is not hard, but it gets hard when the image on the button needs to change after it is clicked for the second time, I can not get this to work properly.

All help, tips and ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 5):

You can add a counter for the number of times the button was pressed and draw as many circles, with increased radius, as necessary, begining from the widest.

For drawing this, take a look at [Java 2D tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! How do I change the Icon of a JButton, because I can not seem to find a answer to that in the JButton api. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Use `setIcon()` method, inherited from `AbstractButton`.